# Form scrolls down and loses navigation focus after changing tabs

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that has 7 tabs.  Not all of the tabs show, so I have a button that unhides the tab when the user selects the button.  The reason for this is to control access to this tab with user security.

Everything works nicely except for the fact that when I click on the button and the tab shows, it also scrolls up for some reason. At this point, I can't even do anything to get to the tabs which have scrolled out of view, and I don't want scroll bars either. I finally had to put a 'back' button so that I could get back to the tab that has the buttons on it at which point, I need to press the arrow keys to see the tabs again.

Here is the code for the 'Spend Plan' button:  an `iSecLevel` of 1 gets to see all of the buttons. `iSecLevel` of 2 only sees the Spend Plan Button

```
Private Sub cmdSP_Click()    
    Select Case iSecLevel    
    Case 2
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(1).Visible = True
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(1).SetFocus
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(4).Visible = True
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(2).Visible = False
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(3).Visible = False
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(5).Visible = False
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(6).Visible = False
        Me.cmdCopyFromServer.Visible = False
        Me.cmdCopyToServer.Visible = False
        Me.cmdCOB.Visible = False
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(6).Visible = False
        strFormState = "Default"
        Spend_Plan_Form_Update     
    Case 1
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(1).Visible = True
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(1).SetFocus
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(4).Visible = True
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(2).Visible = False
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(3).Visible = False
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(5).Visible = True
        Me.TAB_SP.Pages(6).Visible = True
        Me.cmdCopyFromServer.Visible = True
        Me.cmdCopyToServer.Visible = True
        Me.cmdCOB.Visible = True
        strFormState = "Default"
        Spend_Plan_Form_Update
    End Select
End Sub
```

Is it an anchor or centering problem that I am experiencing? I would prefer for all of the tabs to remain visible at the top of the screen.

Comment: Im not sure what the line `spend_plan_form_update` is meant to do? is it something you should be calling?.... In addition, is it possible for you to use `multirow` on your tab control?

Comment: Ok.  Here's the latest.  I did try multirow - nothing.  I tried removing all of the other code except for setfocus to the spend plan and NOTHING fixed it.  But then I tried looking at it on another user's monitor and all of the symptoms were gone.  Huh?  So I've been playing with code and all I need to do is change the monitor?  Should I make the form smaller?  Another thing I've come to notice is that if I press 'Refresh All' I get my tabs back.  So what is this setting that I need to make sure is in place?